# How to initialize basic Authentication header for reactor HttpClient?

Tags: java, spring, reactor-netty

I can add the header in a WebClientBuilder like this:

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl(...).defaultHeaders(header -> header.setBasicAuth(...)[...].build();
```

With the HttpClient I'm trying:

```
HttpClient.create().baseUrl(...).headers(/*not sure how to set the basic authentication here*/)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reactor Netty HttpClient does not provide a shortcut for setting this header.
You should do it by yourself:

```
HttpClient.create().baseUrl(...).headers(h -> h.set("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials))
```